# A flaw with the Stack Overflow reputation system; we're rewarding new users for asking bad questions!

Tags: support, status-norepro, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

There's a flaw with the Stack Overflow reputation system that's affecting new users with very low (or even zero) reputation. And I mean, in a good way for them, but not good for the rest of the community.

---

**Scenario:**

A new user registers for Stack Overflow. They don't read the FAQ or the site rules, they just go straight to asking a question. This leads to a, well, not-so-good-quality question being asked. That question was subsequently closed and received 10 downvotes. After some time, since the question wasn't well-received by the community, either the OP deletes the question or a moderator does. And to the OP's surprise, once the question was deleted they got 20 (21 total) reputation points!

---

That happened because a user's reputation cannot go below 1, and all reputation lost or gained is revoked when a question gets deleted. 10 downvotes (and 0 upvotes) equals -20 reputation, and the user's reputation was already at 1 so it couldn't go any lower, and the -20 reputation was revoked when the question was deleted which gave the user +20 reputation.

This is very bad because the reputation system is basically rewarding new users for asking bad questions (if they get downvoted and deleted, which most bad questions do).

---

**Proposal:**

I propose a change to the reputation system to prevent the above things from happening (low-rep user gets more reputation than they started with after bad post is deleted). If a bad (downvoted and closed not as duplicate) post is deleted, the reputation lost from it will not be returned to the OP.

Comment: Users don't just magically gain reputation that way. They don't get anything back, since they also didn't lost anything. Your proposal is already implemented.

Comment: Retagging this as support, since you need to learn a bit about how the rep system works.

Comment: The feature request tag was removed from your question for a reason. The system does not behave the way you describe, and your feature request is pointless because the problem you're describing does not exist. As stated, you need to learn how the system actually works.

Comment: seriously.... do more research. Meta is like the main site.... stop spamming it with half researched questions.... Or are you trying to figure out if there is a Meta question ban?

Comment: Are you nicael's sibling?  Because I think you're nicael's sibling.  OP's nicael's sibling, isn't he, @patrice?  OP is nicael.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you can point to a specific example in which this happens, the scenario you describe cannot occur.

The way that it works is, since a user cannot drop below 1 reputation, any negative reputation event does not have an effect on their global reputation.  It *will* count against them in terms of the quality filter, but in terms of reputation alone, there will be no impact.

If a user gets spurious upvotes while their question is heavily downvoted, *those* upvotes will factor into any recalculation if/when the question is removed - resulting in them chiefly going away.

If you can find evidence of this occurring, it's worth the bug report, but I've not seen anything like that possibly occurring.